Simplifying sums with CAS or theorem prover
To verify that a certain map is a chain homotopy I could reduce it to an evaluation of
$S = S_1 + S_2$ where
$$
S_1 = \sum_{a=0}^p \sum_{b=0}^{p+1} (-1)^{a+b} n_b \cdot e_a 
$$
$$
S_2 = \sum_{b=0}^p \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{a+b} e_a \cdot n_b
$$
The multiplication $\cdot$ is non-commutative and one has the rules
$$
\begin{align}
n_b \cdot e_a = e_{a-1} \cdot n_b \text{ for } b < a \\
n_b \cdot e_a = e_a \cdot n_{b-1} \text{ for } b > a+1 \\
n_a \cdot e_{a-1} = n_a \cdot e_a
\end{align}
$$
Just as a side note: The $e_a$ and $n_b$ are certain operations on lists of integers $[j_0,\ldots,j_p]$.
By a hand calculation, which I found a bit tedious, I could show
$$
S = n_0 \cdot e_0 - n_{p+1} \cdot e_p
$$
which amounted to the sought for proof.
Variants of such calculations arise often in the context of defining boundary operators in (co)homology or, as here, chain homotopies. So I came to the question whether they could be done with a computer algebra system (CAS) or a theorem prover (like Lean).
I tried to do it with Maple and Mathematica, but it did not work out - after specifying the relations with a 'piecewise' function both systems could not simplify the sums as one would do in a hand calculation but left them in the unevaluated form.
With theorem provers I have no experience - perhaps someone acquainted with Lean or another suitable system could give it a try and write about the result.
I know that the actual calculation above is not of MO level, but my question is about whether these and similar calculations can be automated and if yes, how!

My first step would be to describe the relations in the convenient form for "rewriting e before n to n before e", since that is the form you want the answer in, and currently the relations are written "backwards".
